# BeautifulSoup4 cannot locate table no matter what I try

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape 2 tables from a webpage simultaneously.
BeautifulSoup finds the first table no problem, but no matter what I try it cannot find the second table, here is the webpage: [Hockey Reference: Justin Abdelkader](https://www.hockey-reference.com/players/a/abdelju01/gamelog/2014).

It is the table underneath the Playoffs header.

Here is my code.

```
        sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.hockey-reference.com/players/a/abdelju01/gamelog/2014', timeout=None).read()
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html5lib')
        table = soup.find_all('table')
        print(len(table))
```

Which always prints 1.

If I print(soup), and use the search function in my terminal I can locate 2 seperate table tags. I don't see any javascript that would be hindering BS4 from finding the tag. I have also tried finding the table by id and class, even the parent div of the table seems to be unfindable. Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: lol...I asked that same question a while back (but for football-reference.com site). Here's the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433490/beautifulsoup-only-returning-first-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of javascript loading additional information

Today [requests_html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) can load with html page also javascript content.

```
pip install requests-html

from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.hockey-reference.com/players/a/abdelju01/gamelog/2014')
r.html.render()
res = r.html.find('table')
print(len(res))
4
```

Answer (score 1):

The second table seems to be inside a HTML comment tag `<--... <table class=...`. I guess that's why BeautifulSoup doesn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that table is a widget — click "Share & more" -> "Embed this Table", you'll get a script with link:

https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=hr&url=%2Fplayers%2Fa%2Fabdelju01%2Fgamelog%2F2014&div=div_gamelog_playoffs

How can we parse it?

```
import requests
import bs4
url = 'https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=hr&url=%2Fplayers%2Fa%2Fabdelju01%2Fgamelog%2F2014&div=div_gamelog_playoffs'
widget = requests.get(url).text
fixed = '\n'.join(s.lstrip("document.write('").rstrip("');") for s in widget.splitlines())

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(fixed)
soup.find('td', {'data-stat': "date_game"}).text # => '2014-04-18'
```

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

You can reach Comment line with bs4 Comment like :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup , Comment
from urllib import urlopen


search_url = 'https://www.hockey-reference.com/players/a/abdelju01/gamelog/2014'

page = urlopen(search_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

table = soup.findAll('table') ## html part with no comment
table_with_comment = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in table_with_comment]
## print table_with_comment  print all comment line

start = '<table class'

for c in range(0,len(table_with_comment)):
    if start in table_with_comment[c]:
         print table_with_comment[c] ## print comment line has <table class
```