# Unusual results from BeautifulSoup4 from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from basketball-reference.com and I am not able to get all the table from the `soup`, instead I am only getting 1 table

Code used is this

```
import requests
import bs4

def requestSoup(url):
  res = requests.get(url)
  return bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

soupMaker = requestSoup("https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/ATL/2012.html")
print(len(soupMaker.findAll("table")))
```

Steps to replicate: copy paste above code to https://repl.it/languages/Python3 and hit run

if I do `print(soupMaker)` it gives me whole html which includes many tables but when I do `.findAll("table")` it gives me only one table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the page is dynamic. You'll have to use selenium or use other means to get those other tables. Read my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433490/beautifulsoup-only-returning-first-table)

Comment: Considering the output when you `print(soupMaker)`, there is only one `<table>` tag in the whole html code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am still confused that all the tables are actually in the `soupMaker` variable, including the one I want, but still doesn't shows up on find. Things that are created dynamically should not be in that variable, right?

Comment: @trotta I found all the table in my console/idle maybe it doesn't show up in repl for some reason

Comment: my guess is those `<table>` tags you're referring to are within `<!--` tags. So those are "comments" and won't be parsed or seen by BeautifulSoup. So again, if you want to get those tables, you'll have to use other means. Or I suppose if you took the html string and removed those comment tags, it might work that way.

Comment: @chitown88 thanks mate, everything you said makes sense, selenium thingy worked as well

Comment: @f1uk3r I can understand your confusion, whats within the `soupMaker` variable was on the page at the time of request, so why can't beautiful soup find it?

If you look a little closer at the tables that are in there are surround by html comments `<!-- <table> ... </table> -->'. It appears that the un-commenting of the tables is dynamic. I agree with chitown88, selenium is your best bet

Comment: I also found this post. Talks about how to remove the comment tags. But honestly, haven't tried it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865564/remove-comment-tag-but-not-content-with-beautifulsoup